# Customize syntax highlighting in netrw

Tags: syntax-highlighting, netrw

Right now I am working on a latex project. When I open a netrw/vinegar window, I get following coloring:

[image]

Apparently, certain filetypes are grayed out and other are not. I like the idea to emphasize files which are user input files and those which are generated/binary types.

Netrw has following boolean variable `g:netrw_special_syntax`. It enables  highlighting for certain group of filetypes.  Details can be found in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/netrw.vim`.

However, following file extensions are not specified in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/netrw.vim`, but are still grayed out in my screenshot: `.fdb_latexmk, .log, .aux, .fls, .out, .toc`.

What has to be done to gray out, e.g. the special files of the `minitoc` package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [nobe4](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/1821/nobe4) I figured it out.
The plugin vinegar by tpope adds `netrwSuffixes` to `SpecialKey`.

```
  exe 'syn match netrwSuffixes =\%(\S\+ \)*\S\+\%('.join(map(split(&suffixes, ','), s:escape), '\|') . '\)[*@]\=\S\@!='
  hi def link netrwSuffixes SpecialKey
```

So I have to extend the definition of `'suffixes'` for the latex package `minitoc` generated files to gray them out as it happens for other generated files by latex.

To change the coloring shown in the screenshot, add following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
setlocal suffixes+=.maf
setlocal suffixes+=.mtc
setlocal suffixes+=.mtc0
setlocal suffixes+=.mtc1
setlocal suffixes+=.mtc2
setlocal suffixes+=.ptc
setlocal suffixes+=.stc1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `g:netrw_special_syntax` specify wether you want the special highlight or not, you should not be able to change the files types.

You can add you own syntax to your `.vimrc` if you want:

```
syn match netrwMiniTOC \(\S\+ \)*\S\+\.minitoc\>" contains=netrwTreeBar,@NoSpell
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was actual searching for an answer showing the same way as done for `.fdb_latexmk, .log, .aux, .fls, .out, .toc`. I can't find them in the syntax file $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/netrw.vim.

Comment: I see, you seems to have plugins, can this support be provided by the plugins you use?

Comment: I use vimtex and other unrelated plugins. A `grep netrw` in the plugin folder does not bring up a single match which defines syntax highlighting for netrw files. Can't you reproduce the problem? A simple `touch doc.tex doc.aux doc.maf` should set you up.

Comment: Nop, all files are highlighted the same way

Comment: Sorry, I was to quickly scannig the `grep netrw` results. I found the plugin: it is tpope/vim-vinegar. Thank you very much for your help.